# Error in exprs(eset)

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to read probes from a dat file, put them in a vector then put the vector into a subset to be able to concatenate more data to it and write it in a CSV file. Here my piece of code:

```
library(Biobase)
library(affy)

affys <- read.csv("address of my dat file")
affys_vec <- as.vector(affys)[,1]

exprs(eset)[affys_vec,] -> sub.set

write.csv(sub.set,file="subset.csv")
```

However when I reach to the : `exprs(eset)[affys_vec,] -> sub.set`

I get the following error message:

```
** Error in exprs(eset) :
  error in evaluating the argument object' in selecting a method for function 'exprs':
  Error: object 'eset' not found **
```

Are there any suggestions please?

Thanks,

pqtm

Answer (score 1):

See the vignette [An introduction to Biobase and ExpressionSets](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/Biobase.html) available on your computer, once Biobase is installed, as

```
vignette(package="Biobase", "ExpressionSetIntroduction")
```

But the idea is that you have created `eset` by pre-processing some CEL or other vendor-specific files. How you pre-process those depends on what your files are, maybe with [affy](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/affy.html) or [oligo](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/oligo.html) or [lumi](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/lumi.html), or from a public repository using a package like [ArrayExpress](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/ArrayExpress.html) or [GEOquery](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/GEOquery.html) Or perhaps you're using [limma](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/limma.html) and have no need for an expression set.

The [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) web site and [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) provides a lot more information.